# BigQuery from column to rows by separator

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to generate table and add all values per distinct id to one row using BigQuery

Example:

```
                                  id         label   
000756f4-1af2-439b-b607-ce7384a6b8ee          fast
000756f4-1af2-439b-b607-ce7384a6b8ee     streaming
000756f4-1af2-439b-b607-ce7384a6b8ee         other
0007bac4-1bed-4bf0-8b55-d21216723ef5         issue
000a03d2-f88c-4150-aa96-40b9fdaccb17          fast
000a03d2-f88c-4150-aa96-40b9fdaccb17         other
```

I would like to receive such table:

```
                                  id         label   
000756f4-1af2-439b-b607-ce7384a6b8ee          fast, streaming, other
0007bac4-1bed-4bf0-8b55-d21216723ef5         issue
000a03d2-f88c-4150-aa96-40b9fdaccb17          fast, other
```

Is it possible to achieve it with BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Use `string_agg`:

```
select id, string_agg(label, ', ')
from mytable
group by id
```

**Original answer**

Use `array_agg` and `array_to_string`:

```
select id, array_to_string(array_agg(label), ', ')
from mytable
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `string_agg()`:

```
select id, string_agg(label, ', ') as labels
from t
group by id;
```

Note that the ordering is arbitrary (and might even vary from one run to another).  You might want to include an `order by` as well:

```
select id, string_agg(label, ', ' order by label) as labels
from t
group by id;
```